# Getting a value from json response without header from cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I want a the value of the "token" from the json array from the response i get after performing a cUrl post request. after `print_r($response);` it prints out all that. but i just want the json string and one particular value with php.

Here is my response. I don't want all this before the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK<br/>
Content-Type: application/json<br/>
Content-Length: 312<br/>
Connection: keep-alive<br/>
Vary: Accept-Encoding<br/>
Status: 200 OK<br/>
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate<br/>
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 12:52:25 GMT<br/>
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000<br/>
X-Request-Id: 9418df03bea4e4884522b703d0eec504<br/>
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1<br/>
ETag: "dd4de4d3a6e4e499d6a034ce784d2d76"<br/>
X-Runtime: 0.633173<br/>
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff<br/>
X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass<br/>
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.28<br/>
Server: nginx/1.10.0 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.28

{"response_code":"00","response_text":"Mobile wallet payment request has been issued.","description":"You will receive a bill prompt shortly on your number 0546653444 with invoice no. 201562656, kindly complete it.","transaction_id":"DTV408402","token":"8268dfffa46a16b0665a76","mobile_invoice_no":"201562656"}
```

Comment: What are you using , how are you trying to do ?? give some idea.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, thanks soo much, add it to the answers so i can vote your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Added, accept if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell cURL that you don't want the header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use php's explode() function on this response. Or you can adjust your curl request to not return headers with your requests.

```
$split=explode("\n\n",$response);
$array=json_decode($split[1],true);
var_dump($array);
```

if this does not work, modify explode function to split on "\r\n\r\n" instead of "\n\n";

Answer (score -2):

you can do it with JSON decode.

```
$json = $Your_respone_variable;
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'token'}; // token can be replaced by any other key of your JSON
```

For more informations take a look at:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php